# Server certificates not renewing

Tags: firewall, certificate

Ok, let's see how i get started on this...

We have a new customer with a server and a Cisco firewall. We renewed his server certificates in the Gateway server and in the cisco firewall.

Now, when we want to remotely connect to his server through the RD Gateway we get the following message:
*Your computer can’t connect to the remote computer because the Remote Desktop Gateway server’s certificate has expired or has been revoked. Contact your network administrator for assistance.*

When I check the Certificate information on that message I still see the old certificate. The old certificate has been completely deleted, how is this possible?

Comment: The server probably has not reread the config and the old cert is still in memory.

Comment: How can I apply the new cert and remote the old in this case?

Comment: I dont know + I have not used Cisco hardware for a long time. A reboot shpuld do it though (but wpukd seem drastic)

Comment: Well everything has been rebooted many times now